# Can Entropy decrease through genralized measurement

Tags: entropy, quantum-computer

Can entropy of a quantum state decrease through the generalized measurement?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can decrease entropy by measuring a state with the most simple projective measurement, i.e. measuring a state in the standard basis. Since projective measurements are a particular example of generalized measurements, this is also true for generalized measurements.

This reflects the classical intuition that you should gain information by measuring a state.

Proof. Let $\rho$ the mixed state describing your system of (say) $n$-qubits. If you measure all qubits in the standard basis and obtain $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ as outcomes then the axiom of measurement tells you that the quantum state $\rho'$ of your measured system will be pure (thus with 0 Von Neumann entropy) and of the form $\rho'=|a_1,\ldots, a_n\rangle \langle a_1,\ldots, a_n|$. If your initial state was the maximally mixed state, then you have reduced the Von Neumann entropy from $n=\log 2^n $ to $0$.